# can not access web service with curl_exec()

Tags: php, apache

I have some web service in server 1 .server 1 is centos .I can access web service in the browser but when I want to access web service with `curl_exec()` in php that do not return anything and webpage load for a long time .I think I must create some config in server 1 .can anyone help ?
this is code :

```
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, "http://example.com/");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);
$result=curl_exec($ch);
var_dump($result);
curl_close($ch);
```

Comment: Show what your code so far is

Comment: try to dump the result after closing the connection.

Comment: I remove dump but still not working

Answer (score 1):

Here's the solution I have created for you -

```
<?php

    error_reporting(E_ALL);

    $request =  'http://example.com/';

    // Initialize the session
    $session = curl_init($request);

    // Set curl options
    curl_setopt($session, CURLOPT_HEADER, true);
    curl_setopt($session, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);

    // Make the request
    $response = curl_exec($session);

    //var_dump($response);

    // Close the curl session
    curl_close($session);

    // Get HTTP Status code from the response
    $status_code = array();
    preg_match('/\d\d\d/', $response, $status_code);

    // Check the HTTP Status code
    switch( $status_code[0] ) {
        case 200:
            // Success
            break;
        case 503:
            die('Your call to Web Services failed and returned an HTTP status of 503. That means: Service unavailable. An internal problem prevented us from returning data to you.');
            break;
        case 403:
            die('Your call to Web Services failed and returned an HTTP status of 403. That means: Forbidden. You do not have permission to access this resource, or are over your rate limit.');
            break;
        case 400:
            // You may want to fall through here and read the specific XML error
            die('Your call to Web Services failed and returned an HTTP status of 400. That means:  Bad request. The parameters passed to the service did not match as expected. The exact error is returned in the XML response.');
            break;
        default:
            die('Your call to Web Services returned an unexpected HTTP status of:' . $status_code[0]);
    }

    // Get the XML from the response, bypassing the header
    if (!($xml = strstr($response, '<?xml'))) {
        $xml = null;
    }

    // Output the XML
    echo htmlspecialchars($xml, ENT_QUOTES);
    ?>
```

Comment: thank you for your answere .we have a firewall in our network.this firewall not allow to connect to server 1 .when i disable firewall problem solved.I open all port over the network to access server 1.but i want to know exactly which port need to opened for this case.thank you.